# Clipboard Manager Activity Not Working in Android

Tags: android, clipboardmanager

I have simple **Clipboard Manager** Activity Which Copy And Paste The Data From on EditText To next EditText box but The Activity Not Starting

My **MainActivity** is As Follows:

```
package com.example.clipboarddemo;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ClipboardManager mClipboardManager;
private ClipData myClip;
private EditText copyField,pasteField;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mClipboardManager=(ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    copyField=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    pasteField=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void copy(View view){
    String text=copyField.getText().toString();
    myClip=ClipData.newPlainText("text", text);
    mClipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text Copied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void paste(View view){
    ClipData abc=mClipboardManager.getPrimaryClip();
    ClipData.Item item=abc.getItemAt(0);
    String text=item.getText().toString();
    pasteField.setText(text);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Text Pasted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

and **AndroidManifest.xml** file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.clipboarddemo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I have Read the Following Tutorial To Create This Class:

[Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_clipboard.htm)

Logcat error is showing as follows:

```
    08-30 16:09:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(296): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 16:09:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(296): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.content.ClipboardManager
08-30 16:09:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at com.example.clipboarddemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
08-30 16:09:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-30 16:09:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-30 16:09:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-30 16:09:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-30 16:09:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-30 16:09:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-30 16:09:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-30 16:09:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-30 16:09:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-30 16:09:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-30 16:09:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-30 16:09:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-30 16:09:23.810: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-30 16:09:23.870: W/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity com.example.clipboarddemo/.MainActivity
08-30 16:09:24.862: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4a2d49e0 com.example.clipboarddemo/.MainActivity}
08-30 16:09:25.060: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher: 44069 ms (total 44069 ms)
08-30 16:09:35.673: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{4a2d49e0 com.example.clipboarddemo/.MainActivity}
08-30 16:10:53.140: D/KeyguardViewMediator(59): pokeWakelock(5000)
08-30 16:10:53.320: D/KeyguardViewMediator(59): pokeWakelock(5000)
08-30 16:10:53.690: W/WindowManager(59): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
08-30 16:10:54.370: I/ARMAssembler(59): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00000000_00000000 [ 33 ipp] (47 ins) at [0x577a10:0x577acc] in 602296 ns
08-30 16:10:56.640: I/Process(296): Sending signal. PID: 296 SIG: 9
08-30 16:10:56.660: I/ActivityManager(59): Process com.example.clipboarddemo (pid 296) has died.
08-30 16:10:57.070: I/ARMAssembler(59): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001001_00000000 [ 91 ipp] (114 ins) at [0x577ad0:0x577c98] in 866708 ns
```

Comment: Do you mean that you cannot see your activity? or do you get an exception?

Comment: The App is not Openingn at all

Comment: @hoomi ,i already give the Tutorial Link as well

Comment: The thing is I am not an editor of a blog. I am here to answer your question :). Anyways if the app is not openning at all it means that you have a problem in your manifest. Can you provide your manifest file please?

Comment: i updated the question with manifest

Comment: Your manifest looks fine. Have you tried commenting everything on `OnCreate` except for `setContentView` just to make sure that your app opens with a UI

Comment: i added the log cat error as well

Comment: So you do get an exception. The log message that you added should have a line which says the type of exception. Can you also add that?

Comment: in this much time you should try this on your own system rather than asking me ?

Comment: I hope that you understand I am not only answering your question. I cannot spend time and start a new project for each question.Even if I run it on my machine I cannot know why you are facing that issue. You need to be more informative in your questions if you want answers

Comment: @hoomi have a look i update the full Logcat

Comment: What version of Android is on your phone/simulator `android.content.ClipboardManager` is available on API V11+

Comment: i am running Android 2.2 on emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `android.content.ClipboardManager` is available on Android 3.0.x and above you cannot run it on Android 2.2. That is why you are getting `NoClassDefFoundError` exception.

If you want to use ClipBoard on Android 2.3.x and below I suggest that you use `android.text.ClipboardManager`

I hope that it helps

Comment: but getPrimaryClip() and setPrimaryClip() methods not working with this import.

Comment: Have a  look at the doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html

Comment: For android.text.ClipboardManager you have to use `setText` and `getText` instead of `setPrimaryClip` and `getPrimaryClip`